# SSRS Report Setup

Tags: reporting-services

```
select cast(i.invoicedatetime as date) as Date, oi.DepartmentID, departmentname, SubDepartmentName, sum(Quantity*each*UnitPrice-o.DiscountAmount-i.DiscountAmount) as Sales
from InvoiceInfo i, 
    orderinfo o, 
    OrderItemInfo oi, 
    DepartmentInfo d, 
    SubDepartmentInfo s
where i.InvoiceID = o.InvoiceID
and o.orderid = oi.OrderID
and oi.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
and oi.SubDepartmentID = s.SubDepartmentID
and oi.departmentid in (@DepartmentID)
group by DepartmentName, SubDepartmentName, InvoiceDateTime, oi.DepartmentID
order by DepartmentName
```

Here is the preview view of this report:

[image: Image Number 1]

[image: Here is the Parameter setup for the values]

Is there a way so that our users can run the report and create a SINGLE report but have each of the Department groups grouped together on the report?  I need the totals of each group.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you are viewing  the report right click on the column with Department if that is what you want. The Create a New group based on this. You can then decide how you want them to be seen. If you want to put a page break after each group, then when it exports to excel it puts each group on a different sheet. here is a good tutorial
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx

To add the custom group would be something like:

```
select cast(i.invoicedatetime as date) as Date, oi.DepartmentID, departmentname, SubDepartmentName, sum(Quantity*each*UnitPrice-o.DiscountAmount-i.DiscountAmount) as Sales
from InvoiceInfo i, 
    orderinfo o, 
    OrderItemInfo oi, 
    DepartmentInfo d, 
    SubDepartmentInfo s
    ,case when oi.DepartmentID in (1,12,2,8,14,18,22,28,39) then 'Photo'
            when oi.DepartmentID in (13,20,24,30,44) then 'Press, Books, Albums'
            when oi.DepartmentID in (23,29,36,43,48) then 'Inkjet' end  'CustomGroup'
where i.InvoiceID = o.InvoiceID
and o.orderid = oi.OrderID
and oi.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
and oi.SubDepartmentID = s.SubDepartmentID
and oi.departmentid in (@DepartmentID)
group by DepartmentName, SubDepartmentName, InvoiceDateTime, oi.DepartmentID
order by DepartmentName
```

Comment: Thanks!  I guess I am uncertain how I can create groups from the groups that I have defined in my parameter?

Comment: @JeffreyLazo When you are adding a group instead of just picking a basic thing you would have to set it up to work based on a function. If 1,2,3,4, then 4, else if 5,6,7,8 then 5 etc.  Another option is to create a column in your querry that has the groups calculate for you, this would do 2 things. 1: eliminate the need for you paramenter, it could simply be based on a query of your custom groups. 2: you could group on the custom group this way